# One leg on an object consisting of two legs doesn't get textured for some reason

Tags: texturing, uv

Only one leg gets textured, despite both being unwrapped over the texture properly, texture is baked from a procedural material. Works then it's in the material form, but doesn't when baked into an image.
[image: left leg is untextured for some reason]

Left leg isn't textured, despite the right one working properly.

[image]

Comment: Please attach the file so we can figure out what is causing the problem.

Comment: Have you assigned the good material to the leg? As Arachnoden says, please share your file